# MVC Route Error: The constraint entry 'Length'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

I have a controller called Account with an action with the following signature:

```
public ActionResult Verify(string userName, Guid authorisationToken);
```

I have created a link to call this action thus:

```
/Account/Verify/sachin13/409bdaaa-0b65-4bb8-8695-6e430323d8f8
```

When I go to this link I get the following error:

```
The constraint entry 'Length' on the route with URL 'Account/{Verify}/{userName}/{authorisationToken}' must have a string value or be of a type which implements IRouteConstraint.
```

This is what my RegisterRoutes method looks like in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ,// Parameter defaults
                new[] { "UI.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "AccountVerify",
                "Account/{Verify}/{userName}/{authorisationToken}",
                new { controller = "Account", action = "Verify", userName = "", authorisationToken = "" },
                "UI.Controllers"
            );
        }
```

Two questions:

1. Am I doing anything out of the ordinary or is my methodology here in line with standard practice?
2. What is the problem here?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should change

`"UI.Controllers"`

to

`new[] { "UI.Controllers" }`

in your second route.

If you're specifying only a single string (not an array) then you get wrong overload of `MapRoute` function - instead of `MapRoute(RouteCollection, String, String, Object, String[])` which accept a list of namespaces as last parameter you get `MapRoute(RouteCollection, String, String, Object, Object)` which expects constraints as last parameter. String "UI.Controllers" is not a correct constraint specification => you get the error.

Also as @Pankaj suggested your custom route should go before default and Verify should be without "{}".

Full code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "AccountVerify",
            "Account/Verify/{userName}/{authorisationToken}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Verify", userName = "", authorisationToken = "" },
            new [] { "UI.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ,// Parameter defaults
            new[] { "UI.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Sergey, sir - that was brilliant - it worked.  I owe you are beer.

Answer (score 2):

Always declare your custom route before the Default route so as to make it work as they work in the order from first to last. Therefore you need to declare your second route before the default route and it should solve the problem I suppose. Also, remove the "{}" for Verify in second route

Comment: brilliant comment - thanks Pankaj.  But why do I need to remove the {}?

Comment: To make sure that only "Verify" segment based URL is allowed to use the custom route....If you make use of "{}" , then the URL `/Account/AnyOtherValue/sachin13/409bdaaa-0b65-4bb8-8695-6e430323d8f8` will also direct to the same action rather than showing 404 error.